# Simple Ruby authentication for the Github API v3

Tags: ruby, api, github-api

I'm looking for a bone-simple ruby script:

1. Insert into a *.rb file.
2. Fill in my auth creds.
3. Specify an API URL.
4. Get data back.

As beautiful as the docs for Githubs API are ... there is no simple " hit it and go " example to getting data back within a ruby script.

Answer (score 1):

over at the [GitHub developer libraries page](http://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/#ruby) there's a handful links to ruby libraries. reading the docs on for example the [GitHub API Gem](https://github.com/peter-murach/github) (which describes itself as "A Ruby wrapper for the GitHub REST API v3") it should be trivial to do a quick copy'n'paste to whip up some code using the examples from the [docs](http://peter-murach.github.com/github/).